Quality of geocoding in R with censusxy?
I am trying to geocode addresses using the package "censusxy." An example of how I do this is:
address<-tibble(street="295 Cow Hill Road", city="Mystic", state="CT")
address_geo<-cxy_geocode(address, street="street", city="city", state="state", output="full")

One of the columns of address_geo is "cxy_quality." Does anyone know what is the full set of values this variable "cxy_quality" can take on? I have only seen it take on the value "Exact", but I am not sure if it takes on other values (e.g., semi-Exact)?

cxy_quality represents the TIGER MATCH TYPE field outputted by the geocoding API, which is binary (Exact/Not Exact), per the Census Geocoder User Guide (pg. 31). The censuscy package has also been archived at the request of the maintainer - I would recommend switching over to another package such as tidygeocoder.

I’m voting to close this question because it was already answered well in a comment, and doesn't need a full answer.

@JamesRider That's not a valid reason to close a question. Also, solutions belong in answers, not in comments.

@cristian-vargas In the future, when you know the answer to a question, please post it as an answer, not as a comment.

Oh, I see. I just approved your comment as an answer. Thanks!

Converting solution from a comment to an answer:

cxy_quality represents the TIGER MATCH TYPE field outputted by the geocoding API, which is binary (Exact/Not Exact), per the Census Geocoder User Guide (pg. 31). The censuscy package has also been archived at the request of the maintainer - I would recommend switching over to another package such as tidygeocoder. –
cristian-vargas
2024-07-08 18:02:48Z

